# Specific value element input not read by

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know if its a browser bug or something else, because I have tested on Chrome and Firefox. I get same result. I tried to input value element only 1,10,100 that identified. This's my code.

**HTML**

```
<input id="items" type="text" placeholder="title" value="">
<input id="start" type="text" placeholder="start" value="">
<input id="end" type="text" placeholder="end" value="">
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Generate"><br><br>
<div id="output" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var output = document.getElementById('output');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

var items = document.getElementById('items').value;
var i = document.getElementById('start').value;
var e = document.getElementById('end').value;

for(i; i<=e; i++){ 

output.innerHTML += items+'/'+i;

}

}, false);

</script>
```

It would not generate if **start value** input element is not **1,10,100**. How can I make it to work? Start from **2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9**?

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your values to `Integers`:

```
var i = parseInt( document.getElementById('start').value, 10 );
var e = parseInt( document.getElementById('end').value, 10 );
```

Comment: the 10 is to specify it to be decimal ?

Comment: @яша It's radix value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: can you explain. why is it happen? cause i'm curious.

Comment: @lynxpravoka this happens because `value` DOM property return String, and your for loop should receive Inegers